# Django's admin documentation generator not working

Tags: python, django

I installed docutils.

Then included 'django.contrib.admindocs' in my 'INSTALLED_APPS',

Then, added 'admin/doc' to my url.

When I go to admin/doc, I see the list of things like models, views, filters and etc. It is fine. But when I click on one of those, it says page not found.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: I'm assuming when you said you added admin/doc to your urls.py file it looks something like this? and hopefully you restarted the server? 

(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls'))

Comment: Yes, I did both of the things you mentioned

Answer (score 3):

i know this question is for long time ago but :

Add path('admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')) to your urlpatterns.

[1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/admindocs/)
**Make sure it’s included before the 'admin/' entry, so that requests to /admin/doc/ don’t get handled by the latter entry.**

if you code like this:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
]
```

change it to:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

[The Django admin documentation generator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/admindocs/)